# I am getting java.io.IOException: Broken pipe when the response data is huge

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting java.io.IOException: Broken pipe issue in Higher environment where the code is deployed. But in local system it works fine.
The data is very huge, more than 1000 JSON objects and it takes about 40 seconds to get the response in Local system.

The error logs is as follows 
    `org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:766) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:671) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:376) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:354) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
at org.springframework.session.web.http.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:620) ~[spring-session-core-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:639) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:639) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]`

and so on... Please help. Not finding any solution to fix this.

Comment: You must have some reverse proxy server sitting in front of your app that's dropping connections.

Comment: The solution is for the peer to read the response until its end. If it closes before then, this will happen. You can't fix this at the sending end.